# Can I use a for loop when i have an array of integers

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I'm going through a book of fundamentals of programming and I stumbled on this exercise

Write a program that prints the first 100 members of the sequence

```
2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8
```

And in the solution to the exercise, it says to check for loops chapter

I tried using a for loop  while storing the numbers in an array to solve it but the compiler says it can't convert type `int[]` to `int`

```
int[] numbers = {1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 6, -7};

for (int i = numbers; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: you have to detect the rule for the sequence and generate it - not simply loop over the given values....

Comment: you start with 1 - for each step you add 1 and multiply by -1 - then yououtput it. You do this 100 times...

Comment: check in the for loop. int i= numbers here you are trying to assign number array to i which is an int

Comment: First try to do this on paper/board then try implementing the repetitive task using the loop. You must write your own logic.

Comment: First, you have to detect the rule this sequence of numbers, in their example, they gave the first few numbers, but you want to print the first 100 of those, aslo you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` where u = 7 becuse there are only 6 items in the `numbers` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here isn't to have an array, but to generate the first 100 numbers of this sequence. Each item increments the absolute value by one, and changes the sign:

```
int num = 100;
int start = 2;
int end = start + num;
int sign = 1;
for (int i = start; i < (start + num); i++)
{
    int result = i * sign;
    sign *= -1;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: this is his school/college task, You should not write the logic for him.

Comment: please remove the answer, SO is not a coding service

Answer (score 0):

`var numbers=[1,2,.....100];

Use foreach(int number in numbers){

Console.WriteLine(number);

}`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right, of course. You are assigning `numbers`, which is an `int[]`, to `i`, which is an `int`. These are different types.

But you seem to miss the question at all, unless you think the computer will guess the next items in the sequence from 8 up to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because you tried to use an array as the starting point of the for loop, which only takes an integer.

If you want the starting point to be first entry in your array should write the **index**:

```
for (int i = numbers[0]; i < 100; i++)
```

For further reading take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an array of `int` to primitive int type which is not compatible, that's why you got the compiler error. Instead of this use `forEach` loop. Also, your logic to print the first 100 number is incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i *  Math.Pow(-1, i+1));
}
```

Try this code , should give the output you are looking

Comment: It is not only incorrect, but also doesn't explain why you think it's the right solution.

Comment: duh, print first 100 numbers in the sequence . Please have a look at what he is trying to accomplish

Comment: OK, so you're correct, but you still don't explain how the OP is wrong.

Comment: please check the third comment where i have mentioned what is wrong before placing my  answer